# mysql table bind next row and current row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to get the next row also bound to my query response. for example,

```
SELECT * FROM `ActivityLog` WHERE data like '%865814071038085%'
```

this returns the records i need, with it i also need the next rows to appears in result set,

the table record id's i get with this query are,

```
1,
3,
5,
7
```

So i need a way to get the next rows which are 2,4,6,8 and make the query to out put

```
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8 
records.
```

how can i get the next rows as explained here with mysql ? its always the current row and next very first row.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ActivityLog` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `activityAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `username` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `module` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `controller` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `action` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idxUserName` (`username`),
  KEY `idxUserId` (`userId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='Application activity log' AUTO_INCREMENT=25390 ;
```

Data set,

```
INSERT INTO `ActivityLog` (`id`, `activityAt`, `username`, `userId`, `module`, `controller`, `action`, `data`) VALUES
(1, '2015-03-03 13:02:03', 'guest', NULL, '', 'Site', 'Login', 'Login access. IP:220.247.236.99'),
(2, '2015-03-03 13:02:08', 'QelasySuperAdmin', -1, '', 'Site', 'Login', 'Login success. IP: 220.247.236.99'),
(3, '2015-03-03 13:02:10', 'QelasySuperAdmin', -1, 'Log', 'Activity', 'Admin', 'Manage Activity Logs.'),
(4, '2015-03-03 13:02:17', 'QelasySuperAdmin', -1, 'Log', 'Activity', 'Admin', 'Manage Activity Logs.'),
(5, '2015-03-03 13:06:10', 'guest', NULL, 'Api', 'Default', 'DeviceUsage', ' Data:{"url":"http:\\/\\/www.googleadservices.com\\/pagead\\/aclk?sa=L&ai=CpOAR1LH1VPbZI4GOjAbY2ILQCeikiaQGwIKYmM8Bvtf9EwgAEAEgs_j-GCgDYIEDoAGwhoDQw&val=ChBhOTg3YjE3Y2E3MzM3NWYwEJC5jKcFGggTkt0OPC8P_iABKAAwwZ6E452z_YSAATiQuYynBUDMw9OnBQ&:","id":"1745"}'),
(6, '2015-03-03 13:06:10', 'guest', NULL, 'Api', 'Default', 'DeviceUsage', ' Response:{"code":200,"status":true,"data":[],"serverTime":"2015-03-03 13:06:10"}'),
(7, '2015-03-03 13:06:11', 'guest', NULL, 'Api', 'Default', 'DeviceUsage', ' Data:{"url":"about:blank","id":"1745"}'),
(8, '2015-03-03 13:06:11', 'guest', NULL, 'Api', 'Default', 'DeviceUsage', ' Response:{"code":200,"status":true,"data":[],"serverTime":"2015-03-03 13:06:11"}'),
(9, '2015-03-03 13:06:15', 'guest', NULL, 'Api', 'Default', 'DeviceUsage', ' Data:{"url":"http:\\/\\/clickserve","id":"1745"}'),
(10, '2015-03-03 13:06:15', 'guest', NULL, 'Api', 'Default', 'DeviceUsage', ' Response:{"code":200,"status":true,"data":[],"serverTime":"2015-03-03 13:06:15"}'))
```

**Update**

**Please check this sql fiddle,** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b218a/1

So far none of the answers helped me.

Output of the EXPLAIN command.

[image]

Comment: Provide table structure with sample data.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I sense there are many things inside your head that you haven't clearly let us know about.You haven't told us anything about the ActivtyLog table and the data that is in it and thus why the sample rows have been returned where other rows are not. I have no idea what you mean by  " its always the current row and next very first row." because in the first part of your question you haven't talked about the current row and next row... you talk about odd rows vs even rows... so there's a lot that you aren't telling us that we need to know before we can help

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas check the question, its provided.

Comment: @timeman789 check my answer, provided working sql fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this. should be close.

```
select * from
  (
    SELECT * FROM `ActivityLog` WHERE data like '%865814071038085%'
    union
    SELECT * FROM `ActivityLog` where id in (SELECT id + 1 FROM `ActivityLog` WHERE data like '%865814071038085%') 
  ) q
```

demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b406/5

Just in case the ids are non sequential, here's another:

```
select * from
  (
    SELECT * FROM `ActivityLog` WHERE data like '%FOO%'
    union
    SELECT * FROM `ActivityLog` where id in (SELECT min(a2.id)  FROM `ActivityLog` a1 inner join `activitylog` a2 on a1.id < a2.id WHERE a1.data like '%FOO%' group by a1.id) 
  ) q
```

with updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b406/9

Using the same technique as Anirban N from another answer, but modified to only update the value of `@pid` when its NOT the next sequential id, and only match when its either the searched for value, or IS the next sequential id. (this one will not get the next row if there is a gap in the id sequence)

```
select if(@pid + 1 = id, id, @pid := id) id, 
       activityAt,
       username , 
       userId, 
       module,
       controller,
       action,
       data  
  from `ActivityLog` as a 
  where a.data like '%865814071038085%' 
    or id = @pid + 1;
```

[final fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b218a/63)

Comment: from the question `how can i get the next rows as explained here with mysql ? its always the current row and next very first row.`

Comment: Hmm I still don't read it as such, but if this helps the OP it is obviously faster than my subquery.

Comment: @pala_ it doesnt work. the browser crashes (phpMyAdmin)

Comment: Your tables must be large?

Comment: @pala_  has 25390 records.

Comment: @pala_ is there any better solution ?

Comment: Are you able to increase the php max execution time? Can you sure me the explain plan for the query?

Comment: @pala_ its set to 30 mins, and i tried tweaking the query, this is the part that doesnt work or taking very long time. SELECT * FROM `ActivityLog` where id in (SELECT id + 1 FROM `ActivityLog` WHERE data like '%865814071038085%')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75366/discussion-between-timeman789-and-pala).

Answer (score 0):

May be you can store the result in MySql varibale(@pid) , and use it in next union query,

*Working example*

**Edited Version 2**  ( [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b218a/61/1) )

```
SET @pid:= 0;

SELECT @pid:=id, `activityAt` ,`username` , `userId` , `module` ,`controller`,`action` ,`data`  
FROM `ActivityLog` as a WHERE a.data like '%865814071038085%' OR @pid!=0;
```

Comment: There is an error, #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO @prev_id,* FROM `ActivityLog` WHERE data like '%865814071038085%' UNIO' at line 3

Comment: it still says the same error. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO @prev_id FROM `ActivityLog` WHERE data like '%865814071038085%' UNION ' at line 3

Comment: this answer doesn't work, even on the fiddle it doesnt work - it includes rows with ids `2959,2960,2970` which should not be there. in fact, that query includes EVERY row after the first matching row is found.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, self joining table on next higher Id.

```
SELECT * FROM
  (
    SELECT * FROM `ActivityLog` 
    WHERE data LIKE '%865814071038085%'
    UNION
    SELECT * 
    FROM `ActivityLog` 
    WHERE id IN (
      SELECT t2.id 
      FROM `ActivityLog` t1
      JOIN `ActivityLog` t2
        ON t2.id = t1.id+1 
     ) 
)t
ORDER BY Id
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b218a/60)**

Comment: Its running for a longer without any output. phpmyadmin crashes.

Comment: its not working as expected. here is the sql fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b218a/1